# Report: "SUMIF" within Summary Level Formula

Tags: reporting, roll-up-summary

I am looking to create a sort of customer retention report to essentially highlight accounts that did business within us in the past 1-2 years, but haven't since. Specifically we want to identify these by key products and quantities, so I attempt to create this Summary Level Formula, but unfortunately only get zero back even though I'm positive my Product Code is accurate

`IF(ORDER_ITEM_CUSTOMER_PROD_ID="MYKEY",ORDER_ITEM_QUANTITY:SUM,0)`

Any ideas how I would achieve this or what I'm doing wrong with this current formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the two most relevant help pages on this: [(1)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=building_custom_summary_formulas.htm&type=5) and [(2)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_csf_tips.htm&type=5), seeing your results and doing some extrapolation, it seems like the only usable fields in a Summary Level formula are summarized columns, not columns themselves. Which is a pity.